# satchmo can't handle 500 error

Tags: django, debugging, satchmo

If the quantity of the product is a Unicode character, I get
UnicodeEncodeError at /add/. When I set DEBUG = False, the satchmo
can't handle 500 error,it can't return an HttpResponse object, but the handler404 is ok. I find the following in the apache error log.

```
[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124] mod_wsgi
(pid=10523): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/httpd/
conf.d/myshop.wsgi'.

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124] Traceback
(most recent call last):

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
etc/httpd/conf.d/myshop.wsgi", line 34, in application[Thu Dec 31
23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return _application
(environ, start_response)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/
wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
response = self.get_response(request)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/
base.py", line 134, in get_response

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/
base.py", line 166, in handle_uncaught_exception

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
callback(request, **param_dict)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/
defaults.py", line 24, in server_error

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({})))

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 178, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
self.nodelist.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 779, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 792, in render_node

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
node.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
loader_tags.py", line 97, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
compiled_parent.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 178, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
self.nodelist.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 779, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 792, in render_node

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
node.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
loader_tags.py", line 24, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     result
= self.nodelist.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 779, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 792, in render_node

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
node.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
loader_tags.py", line 24, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     result
= self.nodelist.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 779, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 792, in render_node

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     return
node.render(context)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
__init__.py", line 936, in render

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     dict =
func(*args)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Satchmo-1.0_pre-py2.5.egg/
satchmo_store/shop/templatetags/satchmo_util.py", line 179, in
satchmo_language_selection_form

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]
request = context['request']

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]   File "/
opt/python-2.5.4/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/template/
context.py", line 44, in __getitem__

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124]     raise
KeyError(key)

[Thu Dec 31 23:05:31 2009] [error] [client 192.168.123.124] KeyError:
'request'
```

here is 500.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block navbar %}
   <li class="first"><a href="{{ shop_base }}/">{% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h3>{% trans "Error" %}</h3>
    <h4>{% trans "There was an error with the store.  The admin has been notified." %}</h4>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is base.html:

```
{% load i18n satchmo_category satchmo_google satchmo_util satchmo_currency satchmo_discounts app_plugins normalize_decimal %}
{% block doctype %}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
{% endblock %}
<head>
    {% block extra-head %}{% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheet %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ media_url }}css/style.css" />{% endblock %}
    <title>{% block title %}{{ shop_name }}{% if pagetitle %}: {{ pagetitle }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% plugin_point "page_head" %}
</head>
{% block body %}
contents
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Why does django can not handle the 500 error page?

Comment: Going to be a bit hard to tell, unless you post the code of the 500 handler...

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  Thank you for reminding

Comment: Do you get the same results when running under the development server?

Comment: @Peter Rowell: no, that is a bug, by the way, I have fixed the bug. But I want to know why can django not handle the 500 error page.

Comment: I have no idea why *your copy* can't handle it. Try the following *with the development server*: Try a view with a guaranteed 500 error (I always like 1/0) first with `settings.DEBUG = True` and then with it False. If your 500 page works correctly under the dev server, then try the same thing with your production server: first with `settings.DEBUG = True` and then with it False. Remember, you probably will have to restart your production server for the change to take effect. What you're testing for is a) your 500 page is written correctly, and b) you aren't hitting an environment issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view),

> The default 500 view passes no
>   variables to this template and is
>   rendered with an empty Context to
>   lessen the chance of additional errors

I think you should keep the same approach for your 500.html, by **not** extending base.html, and **not** even reference i18n, and instead keeping it **as simple as possible**.

Consider the context when you get a server error: something got wrong, and you do not know what. You may even be in a situation where not the all of the usual preconditions are fulfilled, and therefore you should maintain the page as simple as possible.
Personally, I even avoid images, relying only on some ASCII art :-)